# How to add radio button and Test schedule with date and time?

Tags: php

I had created the form with some details but I added the radio button and it is not working for getting the values to print on my mail and I have tried to add the date and time using dropdown list but it is not working fine.

the radio buttons should be required.It has to show as in below image as alert for radio button and Test schedule but it is not getting as in the image

Please any one help me.It is very important for me.

My form

```
  <form action="http://www.labwise.in/devel/zensearch/order" id="bookingtest" method="post">
<div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="testname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" id="testname" name="testname" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Test Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="field"> 

            <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="<?php echo $_GET['city']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="location" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Location') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" value="<?php echo $_GET['location']?>" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Location') ?>" />
                </div>

        </li>
        <li class="fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="cname" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Name') ?> </label>
                <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Name') ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="field">
         <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>

            <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
         </li>
          <li>
          <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Sample Collection') ?> </label></li>
          <li>
                <div class="radio_button">
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" value="I will visit Lab"> I will visit Lab
                </div>
                <div>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" value="Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00" > Visit me at home/office +Rs50.00
                </div>
         </li>
         <li>
                <label for="requiredby" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Test Schedule') ?> </label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="requiredby" name="requiredby" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Test Schedule') ?>" style="width: 150px;" />
                        <img style="" title="Select Date" id="date_select_trig" alt="" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl("images/calendar.gif");?> "/>
                        <select name="date_time" id="date_time" class="input-text required-entry validate-select" style="width: 50px;" />
                                    <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--')?></option>
                                    <option value="1"><?php echo $this->__('1')?></option>
                                    <option value="2"><?php echo $this->__('2')?></option>
                                    <option value="3"><?php echo $this->__('3')?></option>
                                    <option value="4"><?php echo $this->__('4')?></option>
                                    <option value="5"><?php echo $this->__('5')?></option>
                                    <option value="6"><?php echo $this->__('6')?></option>
                                    <option value="7"><?php echo $this->__('7')?></option>
                                    <option value="8"><?php echo $this->__('8')?></option>
                                    <option value="9"><?php echo $this->__('9')?></option>
                                    <option value="10"><?php echo $this->__('10')?></option>
                                    <option value="11"><?php echo $this->__('11')?></option>
                                    <option value="12"><?php echo $this->__('12')?></option>
                            </select>
                            <b>:</b>


                    </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
<p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?></span></span></button>
</div>


 </form>

  <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <script src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js')."calendar/calendar-setup.js" ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js') ?>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css"  />
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_calendar')->setTemplate('page/js/calendar.phtml')->toHtml();?>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    if(Validation) {
     Validation.addAllThese([
['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
   function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
// var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
if(v.length > 0){
if(v.length !=10){
    return false;
   }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

    return false;
   }


return true;

}else {
return false;
}

}
   ]])
  };
   var dataForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true); 
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
 Calendar.setup({
 inputField : 'testschedule',
   ifFormat : '%d-%b-%Y',
showsTime: false,
 button : 'date_select_trig',
 singleClick : true,
 });
   // ]]>
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It is likely that it is due to the nesting level!

Comment: could you please suggest the changes.

Comment: I could not make the radio buttons as required and i need to get the id's to  my mail file.

Comment: First I think you need to get ride of the list, what you show on the picture does not look like it needs a list!

Comment: Ok.How to make my fields as in the image

Comment: Ok, I am confused now. 1) What do you mean you are not getting the values to print on your mail and 2) want to do with the form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95645/discussion-between-gacci-and-mouni).

Comment: @Gacci hey please reply me.It is very important for me

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of getting rid of that deep level of nesting.

```js
    var visit = document.getElementById('visit-required');
    var form = document.forms.bookingtest;
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
       if(!form.lab.checked && form.office.checked){
         e.preventDefault(); 
         visit.style.display = 'block';
         
       }
    });
```

```css
.marked-required{
    color: #FF0000;
}
.message-required{
    display: none;
    color: #FF0000;
}
#options{
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
#datetime > input{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
Place this php in the file you want to post to.
/* example.php */
<?php
  print_r($_POST);
?>

<form action="example.php" id="bookingtest" method="post">
<strong>Sample collection <span class='marked-required'>*</span></strong>
<div id='options'>
    <input type='radio' name='visit' id='lab'/>I will visit Lab<br/>
    <input type='radio' name='visit' id='office'/>Visit me at home/office + Rs50.00
 </div>
<small class='message-required' id='visit-required'>Please select one of the option.</small>
<br/>
<strong>Test schedule<span class='marked-required'>*</span></strong>
<div id='datetime'>
    <input type='text' />
    <select>
        <option>From</option>
    </select>
     <select>
        <option>To</option>
    </select>
     <select>
        <option>AM</option>
        <option>PM</option>
    </select>
  
    <small class='message-required'>This is a required option</small>
</div>
<input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Ok.Then how to get those values to another file.

Comment: What do you mean yo another file?

Comment: I have a another file as mail.phtml i need to get these values and print the body part of my mail.As if person select  any radio button it  should be display as "Sample Collection:I will visit Lab"

Comment: you mean you want to post?

Comment: Ok, so first of all your page needs to be some sort of .php, .asp or the like (server-side language). Then, action will be set to the page you want to post to, last echo in the page you are posting to.

Comment: And one more thing the red alert messages should be display when no selection is done after clicking on the submit button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95647/discussion-between-gacci-and-mouni).

Comment: I asked you when no selection is done for those radio button and test schedule field,when i click on the submit button.It gets an alert as in the image for that I have provided the image.

Comment: I know, and I replied to you in the chat. You have to follow directions. This conversation has been moved to the chat.

Comment: I could not see any messages in chat

Comment: When you click in the box to post a message, it shows something like this  ...  Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?  YOU HAVE TO CLICK ON THAT. This is too many comments YOU NEED TO MOVE IT TO THE CHAT    http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95647/discussion-between-gacci-and-mouni